# Spring request param enum validation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, enums, request, spring-restcontroller

I'm having my @RestController with service endpoint which takes enum as the parameter. This enum has 4 values but I would like to constraint the user to choose only from two of them. Something like

```
@RequestParam @Min(value= 1, message = "lorem ")
            @Max(value = 10, message = "yfufhu")
```

but for enum - validating if given param is in `{value1,value2}`

Is there anyway to do it?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To validate the path variable , the controller class should be annotated with @Validated.

```
@RestController
@Validated
public Class RestController(){
//...code
}
```

[check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61335462/13302453)

Hope it helps!!