# @Valid working with @ModelAttribute, not with @RequestAttribute

Tags: spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc

I'm implementing a `@RestController` and I realized that `@Valid` is working with `@RequestBody` or `@ModelAttribute` params of a `@GetMapping` method, but not with a `@RequestAttribute` parameter.

To get validated the `@RequestAttribute` annotated param I have to annotate my Controller class with `@Validated`.

Following my code:

1. Controller

   ```
   @Log4j2
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/test/api/v1/entity")
   public class MyController extends SomeController {

     @GetMapping("/getInfo")
     public ResponseEntity<<MyResponse>> infoStatus (RequestParam(required = false) String inputStr,
     @Valid @RequestAttribute ObjectToValidate objToValidate){
          //Any stuff here
     }
   }
   ```
2. Bean to validate

   ```
   @Getter
   @Setter
   @Valid 
   public class ObjectToValidate {

     @NotNull
     @NotEmpty
     private String anyCode;
   }
   ```

The result is anyCode is not checked to be not null nor empty.
If I annotate MyController with `@Validate`, the `ObjectToValidate` param is validate as expected.
If I change controller as follows, the validation also works.

```
    @Log4j2
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/test/api/v1/entity")
    public class MyController extends SomeController {

        @ModelAttribute 
        public ObjectToValidate addToModel(@RequestAttribute ObjectToValidate
        objToValidate) { return objToValidate; }

        @GetMapping("/getInfo")
        public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> infoStatus (
                @RequestParam(required = false) String inputStr,
                @Valid @ModelAttribute ObjectToValidate objToValidate
        ){
           //Any stuff here
        }
   }
```

Please, could you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

@Valid can be used on @RequestBody Controller Method Arguments.
That is @RequestBody method argument can be annotated with *@Valid to invoke automatic validation*.

It will be no use if you annotate ObjectToValidate class with @Valid.

```
@PostMapping("/notes")
Note getNote(@Valid @RequestBody Note note) {
    return repository.save(note);
}
```

To validate the path variable, the controller class should be annotated with @Validated

```
@RestController
@Validated // class level
public class NoteController {

    @GetMapping("/note/{id}")
    Note findOne(@PathVariable @NotBlank(message = "Id must not be empty") String id) { 
        return repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NotekNotFoundException(id));
    }

}
```

Hope it helps!!